# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type Posts

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to get the information stored in the Firebase database and show it in the form of a list. The information is pulled correctly, the debugger shows it is present in the variables. But after going through them and setting the text views it throws an exception of:

Error Logs :

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert an object of type java.lang.String to type com.dodo.seminar.Posts
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dodo.seminar, PID: 6841
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.dodo.seminar.Posts
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:423)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:214)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:79)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:212)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:151)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:140)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:183)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1888)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:407)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:693)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM79d.png)

```
public class PostsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUserRef;
    private FloatingActionButton mButton;
    private RecyclerView mPostsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mButton = findViewById(R.id.posts_floatingActionButton);
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        }
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");

        mPostsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.posts_list);
        mPostsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mPostsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder>(
                Posts.class,
                R.layout.posts_single_layout,
                PostsViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final PostsViewHolder postsViewHolder, final Posts posts, int position) {
                postsViewHolder.setStartingLocation(posts.getStarting_location());
                postsViewHolder.setDestination(posts.getDestination());
                postsViewHolder.setDescription(posts.getDescription());

            }
        };

        mPostsList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }


    public static class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        static View mView;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;


        public PostsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        }

        public static void setStartingLocation(String name) {
            TextView postsTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.posts_single_starting_location);
            postsTextView.setText(name);
        }

        public static void setDestination(String comment) {
            TextView postsTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.posts_single_destination);
            postsTextView.setText(comment);
        }

        public static void setDescription(String comment) {
            TextView postsTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.posts_single_description);
            postsTextView.setText(comment);
        }


    }
}



public class Posts {


    private String starting_location;
    private String user_uid;
    private String destination;
    private String description;
    private String time;

    public Posts(String starting_location, String user_uid, String destination, String description, String time) {
        this.starting_location = starting_location;
        this.user_uid = user_uid;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.description = description;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public Posts() {
    }

    public String getStarting_location() {
        return starting_location;
    }

    public void setStarting_location(String startingLocation) {
        this.starting_location = startingLocation;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUser_uid() {
        return user_uid;
    }

    public void setUser_uid(String user_uid) {
        this.user_uid = user_uid;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should attach the full stacktrace from logcat, so we can see the root cause

Comment: Have tried using GSON ?

Comment: No, I have not. This is the 2nd place I'm using this code. The first one is when listing all the users and there it works without a problem, the data structure is the same and the code virtually the same with the same layouts.

Comment: At which line of code are you getting that error? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo The debugger shows that the code starts breaking after the
 "postsViewHolder.setDescription(posts.getDescription());" in the OnStart method.
Then it goes into the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and inside of it breaks

Comment: Show us the exact line at which it occurs.

Comment: @AlexMamo I do not know in which exact line it occurs. The program goes into the internal functions of Firebase after the call of populateViewHolder, after that it throws out an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You receive string and try to interpret it as Posts object.

Try to store received data in String and use Gson to create Posts object from this json.